# Run one test from testNG within suite

Tags: java, testng

My test.xml file is as below

```
<suite name="suitename">

<test name="testname1">
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.org.test1" />
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="testname2">
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.org.test2" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I try to use command line  `java org.testng TestNG test.xml -testname testname2` to just run the second class. however, it run both of the tests.

How to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get a answer for question other than using exclude tag 
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is command to execute requited tests from testng.xml from command prompt

```
  java -cp ".\bin;.\lib\*;" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml -testnames Test1
```

i hope you used -testname which invokes defult suite.

```
  Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
Options:
-configfailurepolicy
   Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
-d
   Output directory
-dataproviderthreadcount
   Number of threads to use when running data providers
-excludegroups
   Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
-groups
   Comma-separated list of group names to be run
-junit
   JUnit mode
   Default: false
-listener
   List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener or

   ISuiteListener
-methods
   Comma separated of test methods
   Default: []
-methodselectors
   List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
-mixed
   Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with
   appropriate runner
   Default: false
-objectfactory
   List of .class files or list of class names implementing
   ITestRunnerFactory
-parallel
   Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
   Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none, true, false]
-port
   The port
-reporter
   Extended configuration for custom report listener
-suitename
   Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or
   source code
-suitethreadpoolsize
   Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
   Default: 1
-testclass
   The list of test classes
-testjar
   A jar file containing the tests
-testname
   Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source
   code
-testnames
   The list of test names to run
-testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
   The factory used to create tests
-threadcount
   Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
-usedefaultlisteners
   Whether to use the default listeners
   Default: true
-log, -verbose
   Level of verbosity
-xmlpathinjar
   The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if -testjar

   was specified)
   Default: testng.xml
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hi Murali, If I use -testnames, the does @BeforeSuite method in other method run or not. It seems it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `exclude` tag in `testng.xml` file, if we want to skip the execution of any part of test cases. Please find below xml file which skips the execution of `testname1` test:

```
<suite name="suitename">

<test name="testname1">
    <classes>
        <exclude
             name="com.org.test1" />
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="testname2">
    <classes>
        <class
             name="com.org.test2" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Hope this helps.