# How to run a set of classes under single test tag in testng suite?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-2, testng

I have this testng suite segregated under test tag.

This is different interms of other issues ([TestNG surefire, run suite with maven command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391312/testng-surefire-run-suite-with-maven-command-line)). Here I need to execute set of classes under test tag not specific class nor specific package.

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
      <test name="set-1" >
        <classes>
           <class name="com.test.ejb.AdminServiceTest" />
           ....
        </classes>
      </test>
      <test name="set-2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.ejb.ServiceTestBase" />
            ...
        </classes>
      </test>
        <test name="set-3">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.ejb.RazakIeraTest" />
            ...
        </classes>
      </test>
        <test name="set-4">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.ejb.PayCheckTest" />
            ...
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

I have a suite with a grouping of classes under test tag. I would like to execute only one test tag.

We have a way to select single class using this cmd `mvn test -Dtest="className"`.

I have tried -Dtestnames=set-5 (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html). but it did not work.

Do we have any way to execute test tag using maven command ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG surefire, run suite with maven command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391312/testng-surefire-run-suite-with-maven-command-line)

Comment: @NickDeFazio I got a way to select single class,specific package and specific method in a particular class. Is there a way to execute set of class under <test> tag ?

Comment: Do you want to run just one test by name ? can you use command line instead of maven?

Comment: Yes @user1207289. I would like to run just set-1 (classes under test tag). Yes Please provide a way to run single test by command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use maven with maven-surefire-plugin to run your tests, right?

Then in the properties section of the plugin add 'testname' with some variable as a value

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>testnames</name>
        <value>${testng.testnames}</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

You can filter your tests by specifying value of the variable

```
mvn test -Dtestng.testnames=set-1,set-2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command

```
java -cp ".\bin;.\lib\*;" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml -testnames Test1
```

you can also provide a list of test names in `-testnames` parameter

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949001/run-one-test-from-testng-within-suite)

Comment: Here - testnames Test1 refers to the class name right ?.